# Visualising data with javascript graphs - dynamically

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, data-visualization, plotly

Right now I'm using [plot.ly](http://plot.ly) javascript library to visualise an array of numbers. I want to update this plot in every iteration. I tried to `Plotly.newPlot('id',data);` after values changed, however it takes time to re-define plot object every time.

I went through [plot.ly documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotly-relayout) yet did not find a solution for my case.

I want to update graph in every interruption, maybe I need to update plot more 200 times after calling iterating function. Any solutions/suggestions for this problem? I can use another plotting library if there is one fits for this case.

Answer (score 6):

Try `Plotly.extendTraces`

Unfortunately no official examples are available at the moment.

I'd recommend:

- looking the source code [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_api.js#L1346), and
- the test cases [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/test/jasmine/tests/plot_api_test.js#L371).

Comment: Thanks! I also found this, quite helpful: http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/LGEyyY?editors=001

Comment: I'm using like this:
`var update = {y: itemList};` and
`Plotly.extendTraces('myDiv', update,[0],50);`
Getting this exception: "attribute y must be an array of length equal to indices array length"
How should I use this?

Answer (score 2):

Bedi, unfortunately, I cannot respond to your comment directly. I don't have enough points (I need 50 and I have 15). `Plotly.extendTraces()` is what you need. The error you've noted is because `update.y` needs to be an array with a length equal to that of the `indices` argument to `Plotly.extendTraces()`. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_api.js#L1259), indices is the third argument to the `extendTraces`. Your `indices` argument is only one item long (`[0].length === 1`). As long as `itemList` is an array of length 1 you should not be having a problem. Run `console.log(itemList.length === [0].length)` and I think you'll discover that you're trying to add too many points at once to your trace.